# Post Processing to Lazy-Sequences (Clojure)

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation, clojurescript, lazy-sequences

Say I'have a lazy sequence called numbers that's giving me an infinite sequence of numbers: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...

```
(def numbers (iterate inc 0))
```

I limit the infinity by passing it to the function take. e.g.:

```
(take 3 numbers)
; > (0 1 2)
```

I'm asking myself how to add some post-processing to the members of the lazy sequence. More concretely: 
How would I declare a function "numbers-doubled" that would produce the following output, when I use take:

```
(take 3 numbers-doubled)
; > ("00" "11" "22")
```

Comment: `(iterate inc 0)` is just `(range)`

Comment: right! well.. but why not

Comment: The only case for not is when you really care about avoiding chunked sequences, which is usually a problem elsewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a map function in between your `iterate` function and the `take`. Since `map` is lazy, it will only consume as many as requested by the later `take` function.

```
(take 3 (map #(str % %) numbers))
```

You could easily def that map to make it its own infinite sequence:

```
(def numbers-doubled
  (map #(str % %) numbers))

(take 3 numbers-doubled)
```